# Postgres and Replication

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I am not too familiar with Bucardo and Postgres , so I was hoping to get some feedback / how to from this question.

We have 3 computers running in parallel in various parts of the building.   When one updates something the other shows the data etc thanks to bucardo syncs running between the computers.

However here is the requirement.  At anytime one computer can be brought offline and reimaged.   Now when this computer comes back on line, the operator should be able to hit replicate and get the data from the master computer.
What is the best way to accomplish this ?
My thought was to run a pg_dump on the master computer and run pg_restore on the reimaged computer.

or do you think setting bucardo onetimecopy=2 is the best course of action.

Comment: Do you already have bucardo running, or are you asking if using bucardo will help with this?

Comment: I have bucardo running.

Comment: Do you need only a certain subset of tables replicated, or do you need all tables replicated from one machine to the other? I’m asking because based on your requirement, it may make sense to ditch bucardo and instead just use the built-in streaming replication. Then, when you re-image, you just need to do a `pg_basebackup`

Comment: Btw thanks for your response.   I have to replicate the entire dataset.   I am going to read into basebackup and get back to you.

Comment: Basebackup could possible work, setting bucardo onetimecopy=2 did not work for sure.